# Inline images not displaying correctly?

Tags: bug, images

The images in https://mathoverflow.net/a/123671/3 are not displaying properly (checked in Chrome and Firefox), but I'm not sure why. Loading the given URLs in a new tab works fine.

Comment: As the comments on the post from March 2013 show, the problem was already there before the migration to MathOverflow 2.0. A possible reason why the images are not displayed may be that the image file names have no extensions (*.png, etc.), but I don't know.

Comment: @StefanKohl's suggestion seems reasonable. When I tried to put image from http://www.freeimagehosting.net/newuploads/ta8ni.png into a post, it worked fine (at least in preview - I did not submit the post). The link in the post you mentioned is http://www.freeimagehosting.net/ta8ni

Answer (score 4):

I suppose the problem which was suggested by [Stephan Kohl](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1012/inline-images-not-displaying-correctly#comment4502_1012), i.e. missing extension. I [suggested an edit](https://mathoverflow.net/review/suggested-edits/7286) which changed the links from links like http://www.freeimagehosting.net/ta8ni to links to the actual png picture: http://www.freeimagehosting.net/newuploads/ta8ni.png . The post seems to be fine after this edit.

My personal opinion is that it would be better to upload the picture using imgur, since this would make the link more durable and prevent link rot. (Images uploaded via imgur should [exist indefininetely](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/new-image-upload-support/), at least in theory.) But I leave this to the OP (or other people willing edit the post further).

Comment: Even better would be to re-upload them through the new SE interface, which might be the most durable solution of all.

Comment: Well, that's what I meant (SE [uses imgur](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/new-image-upload-support/) for images, if I am not mistaken.)